# Where can I download the "Samsung Galaxy Pro PC Suite"?

Tags: samsung

Where can I download the "Samsung Galaxy Pro PC Suite"? I cannot find it.

Comment: I'm not sure it was worth it to [cross-post this](http://superuser.com/questions/311798/where-should-i-download-the-samsung-galaxy-pro-pc-suite).

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean SAMSUNG Kies, PC Sync?
Try on Samsung [website](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/supportDownloadCenter.do), choose your exact model of Galaxy, and you'll find the available software.